# Splitting joint strings in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, split

I have the following dataframe:

```
CIIU

A3456
A2345
C5433
K5443
T7654
```

And I want to get:

```
A 3456
A 2345
C 5433
K 5443
T 7654
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
df['New']=df.CIIU.str[0]
df['New2']=df.CIIU.str[1:]
df
    CIIU New  New2
0  A3456   A  3456
1  A2345   A  2345
2  C5433   C  5433
3  K5443   K  5443
4  T7654   T  7654
```

Comment: Perfect. And what if I want 'A3' '456', 'A2' '345' and so on...

Comment: @Guerra str[:1] str[2:] :-)